# I keep getting this dark black screen in my flutter app

Tags: dart, flutter

Every page in my app shows black screen when navigated to, I want to believe this is just a minor issue, any help on why am getting this black screens that once worked would be highly appreciated.

My code is on this link:
https://github.com/Kelvinkins/MySnipets/blob/master/BlackScreenIssueInFlutter

Comment: I had the same problem and I resolved it by checking all my widgets.its an error due to widget positioning

Comment: I was able to resolve it, it's truly due to widget positioning.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely caused by the arrangement of Widgets on the screen. Try taking a step back, remove the Widgets used on `Widget build()` and add them one by one to see if they're being displayed as expected.